# Is it possible to manually trigger a flow on list using SharePoint interface

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have an instant flow on a SP list, which accepts a parameter > Get Items > filter by the parameter and automatically creates some entries in other lists.

This flow works perfectly on flow.microsoft.com but I cannot find a way to call this flow on SharePoint list, on SP interface, without actually going to flow site.

Is this possible? I'm hoping it's a yes!

Thank you!
Ova

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online, we could use "For a selected item" trigger to manually execute the flow from a SharePoint list:

[image]

Simple test:

[image]

If it is not feasible for you, please feel free to reply.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#for-a-selected-item

Comment: I want to trigger the flow on the list - not the item if that makes sense?

Comment: There is no OOB way to achieve this, if you doesn't select the item, the flow will not able to retrieve the trigger.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I am glad to hear that my reply is helpful to you.